# Authentication issue with bash script

Tags: bash

It works ("klist -A" shows valid principal):

```
password="<some_pwd>"  
user="karim"  
department="JUS" 
echo $password | kinit $user@$domain.GOV 
Password for karim@JUS.GOV:
```

But with the script I got the error:

```
Enter Password :Password for karim@JUS.GOV: kinit: Password incorrect while getting initial credentials
*Password for karim@JUS.GOV: kinit: Password incorrect while getting initial credentials
*Password for karim@JUS.GOV: kinit: Password incorrect while getting initial credentials
```

Each password's letter typing leads to the above message.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

password="" 
echo "Provide user: " 
read user

echo "Provide department's name (JUS, FIN, MIL): " 
read department

pass_var="Provide password:" 
while IFS= read -p "$pass_var" -r -s -n letter 
do
            if [[ $letter == $'\0' ]]
            then
                break
            fi
            password=password+"$letter"
            pass_var="*"
            if [[ $department == JUS ]];then
                echo $password | kinit $user@$department.GOV
            fi 
done
```

Also, if user specify the department as JUS, FIN or MIL then the kinit command should be executed with the correct set department. I tried something like that but it does not work:

```
if [[ $department == JUS || FIN || MIL ]];then
```

Comment: you should do https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/pasc/1.1.1?topic=credentials-keytab-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixing obvious errors:

```
#!/bin/bash

password=""

read -p "Provide username: " user
read -p "Provide department's name (JUS, FIN, MIL): " department

pass_var="Provide password: "

while IFS= read -p "$pass_var" -r -s -n 1 letter 
do
    if [[ $letter == $'\0' ]]
    then
        break
    fi
    password="$password$letter"
    pass_var="*"
done
echo

if [[ $department == JUS ]]
then
    echo "$password" | kinit "$user@$department.GOV"
fi
```

You can use a `case` or bash's `=~` to match departments:

```
# ...
if [[ $department =~ JUS|FIN|MIL ]]
then
    echo ...
fi
```

```
# ...
case "$department" in
    JUS|FIN|MIL) echo ... ;;
esac
```

Comment: I see that there was not quotation marks in my script and also the second if should be outside. This "read -p" is really nice, much more readable then what I had.
Now it works, thank you. 
Can you elaborate why do you remove + between password and letter variables?

Comment: You mean if the user types `abc` you want the password to actually be `+a+b+c` ?

Comment: @ jhnc, should not be `;` in your example after the `if [[ $department =~ JUS|FIN|MIL ]]` ?

Comment: newline and `;` are equivalent in this context